# Recurrent definition of alcohol content via hazing (5, 2, 9)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Recurrent definition of alcohol content via hazing (5, 2, 9).

I'm completely stumped.

It's a stand alone clue. Not part of a crossword.

Comment: Can you include where you saw the clue in your question?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really what we were asking - we want to know *who made the puzzle*, see [the attribution FAQ](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide)

Comment: Attribution was given in the comments to the recently closed duplicate. If I understand correctly, it's from an ongoing competition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> "Alcohol content via hazing" is an odd way to say "[proof](//enwp.org/alcohol_proof) by [induction](//enwp.org/hazing)", [which](//enwp.org/mathematical_induction) is *sort of* "recurrent definition".

Comment: Ah, beat me to it, well done!

Comment: Seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> PROOF BY INDUCTION

Reasoning

> "Recurrent definition" might be the definition here with "alcohol content" indicating "proof" and hazing indicating "induction"